# Dictionary parsing C#

Tags: c#, dictionary

I want contain my data in this structure:

```
Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, List<double>>> carInfo =
     new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, List<double>>>();
```

And i want to parse it.
I add some data to this dictionary like this:

```
adder.addCarItem("brand1", "type1", 1000, 1);
adder.addCarItem("brand2", "type2", 1000, 1);
```

finally i want to output all this structure like as:

```
 foreach(KeyValuePair<string, Dictionary<string, List<double>>> car in warehouse.GetCarInfo)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(car.Key);

            foreach(var type in car.Value)
            {                    
                Console.WriteLine(type.Key);
                for(int i = 0; i < type.Value.Count; i++)                    
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(type.Value[i]);
                }
            }
        }
```

and it output

```
brand1
type1
type2
brand2
type1
type2
```

but i want to output like this

```
brand1
type1
1000
1
brand2
type2
1000
1
```

How best to implement this parsing for this structure? maybe anybody know...

Code how i add items to dictionary

```
Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, List<double>>> carInfo =
     new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, List<double>>>();
    Dictionary<string, List<double>> carType = new Dictionary<string, List<double>>();
    List<double> countAndCost = new List<double>();

    public void addCarItem(string carBrand, string brandType, double carsNumber, double carCost)
    {

        countAndCost.Add(carsNumber);
        countAndCost.Add(carCost);
        carType.Add(brandType, countAndCost);
        carInfo.Add(carBrand,carType);
    }
```

Comment: Show your code for `addCarItem`. My guess is, it doesn't add anything to your `List<double>`.

Comment: It sounds like you would benefit from storing information in custom classes rather than dictionaries. `Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, List<double>>>` is a pretty painful type to use.

Comment: @EricJ. i add code to question.

Comment: You need to create a new ``carType`` dictionary for each entry of ``carInfo``.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's look at the code you use to add data to your data structure

```
public void addCarItem(string carBrand, string brandType, double carsNumber, double carCost)
{

    countAndCost.Add(carsNumber);
    countAndCost.Add(carCost);
    carType.Add(brandType, countAndCost);
    countAndCost.Clear();
    carInfo.Add(carBrand,carType);
}
```

The line `countAndCost.Clear();` clears out your `List<double>`. That's why nothing is displayed. A list is a reference type, so changes made to it at any point are visible to any part of your program that has a reference to the list.

Remove that line and move your allocation of carType into the add method I suspect it will work.

```
public void addCarItem(string carBrand, string brandType, double carsNumber, double carCost)
{
    Dictionary<string, List<double>> carType = new Dictionary<string, List<double>>();        countAndCost.Add(carsNumber);
    countAndCost.Add(carCost);
    carType.Add(brandType, countAndCost);
    // You can't "re-use" this variable:
    // countAndCost.Clear();
    carInfo.Add(carBrand,carType);
}
```

Comment: Sorry, it's my carelessness
I remove it, but now i have this output:
brand1
type1
1000
1
1000
1
type2
1000
1
1000
1
brand2
type1
1000
1
1000
1
type2
1000
1
1000
1

Comment: See my edit. You need to move `carType` into `addCarItem`.